# Game Programming Junior Demo Design

Tags: game-design, game-industry, jobs, demo

Consider the following demo:

http://www.ashereinhorn.com/post/11140243390/short-capture-from-the-last-xna-version-direct3d

(It has now almost been converted to C++ and DirecX10, and so the code is not important here, it's the substance I'm interested in)

Basically the little agents move around killing each other, their states are displayed in a corner and you can select one so as to see the items it can see, it's field of view and the things it is holding in memory.

I showed it to someone that works in the industry and they said I should focus on tracking a single agent and make what's going on more clear - so maybe animate each state with simple animations or model swapping to make it more obvious when they are searching / in combat / running away. The other thing they said I should change was the fact that the agents simply disappear when killed, and reappear when spawned because again, it's not clear what's happeneing. As a result I'm going to implement a simple particle system so that agents 'shatter' when killed and possibly reassemble when spawned.

My question is, are there any really obvious changes that I should make to this demo with a view to getting my first game programming job? If you work or know about the industry, is there anything that jumps out at you that should be included? Or is bad? or good for that matter?

Are there any things that would particularly impress or grab your attention in a game demo?

Thank you very much for any help you can give!

**EDIT** - The walls are actually solid in the C++ version

Comment: This question is essentially asking for a portfolio review, and while it might be a games portfolio, it's not really a useful question to other people here on GDSE, so I've voted to close.

Comment: @JoshPetrie fair enough, but it was very useful to me. thanks again everyone. Now >1 year in the industry :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off topic, I really like your CV and portfolio presentation so thumbs up on that.

In regards to the video, I agree with the advice that has been given to you so far. Make the agents so that they are recognisable from each other (e.g. make them a different colour). When they change state, do something like add a Metal Gear style '!' appear above their head when they are shooting and maybe a running man icon when they are running to make it more obvious what is going on.

If you have any write up on how it all works, that would be good to read/show if possible.

Do you have any other scenarios for the agents? Eg 2 v 2?

Do you have any other demos like the one that was made for the award shown on your CV?

Comment: Thank you for your comments. and actually yes I do, I'm not really sure why I haven't put that up, although I think it's because with that it's hard to pinpoint which parts I've done myself as it was such a collaboration, but I suppose I should. although another point is that it was my first experience working on a project of any notable size and the code is, well.. crap. in every way. as for other scenarios, that's something I haven't done yet but maybe I should.

Comment: You don't have to always show the code, a decent video trailer and breakdown on the parts you worked on would be fine IMO. I remember one project I put up years ago and a shudder whenever I look at the code today. However the video and the write up was pretty good at the time so I sort of got away with it ;)

Comment: oh ok, good advice. I think I'll do that!

Comment: In fact, here it is: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/357697/portfolio_old/mgs2d.html This is my old portfolio and has pieces of work that I showcased when I first joined. The videos don't work but hopefully it gives a rough idea.

Comment: what a great demo! Thanks for sharing. Making these things really makes you appreciate all the work that goes into the minutia of something like this.